# Android Custom Typeface

Tags: android, typeface

Hi I am using a custom `Typeface` in my app with the following code:

```
public Typeface font;
//Activity on create:
 font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"DINOT-Medium.otf");

TextView tv = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv.setTypeface(font);
```

The problem is after a while it gets buggy: the text can no longer be read and only squares are visible. Do you know why this happens? How can it be fixed?
Thanks

Comment: The code seems alright. Try testing with a different font. I don't know what is otf, but you can try a ttf maybe. For example with this: http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1131

Comment: exactly the otf extension resulted to be the problem, has to be ttf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Mobiletuts+ there is very good tutorial on Text formatting for Android. Quick Tip: [Customize Android Fonts](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/customize-android-fonts/)

EDIT: Tested it myself now. Here is the solution. You can use a subfolder called fonts but it must go in the assets folder not the res folder. So

```
assets/fonts
```

Also make sure that the font ending I mean the ending of the font file itself is all lower case. In other words it should not be myFont.TTF but myFont.ttf

Comment: Thanks actually the problem was that the extension was otf and not ttf... I have converted it here: http://www.convertissez.fr/font-converter.php and now it seems to have been fixed

Answer (score 3):

Create a Custom `TextView` like this :

```
public class DINOTMediumTextView extends TextView {

    public DINOTMediumTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setCustomFont(context);
    }

    public DINOTMediumTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setCustomFont(context);
    }

    public DINOTMediumTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setCustomFont(context);
    }

    private void setCustomFont(Context context) {
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/DINOT-Medium.otf");
        setTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```

put the font's file in `assets/fonts/` ( **create a folder inside the assets folder**)

and then in your layout xml :

```
<com.yourapp.views.DINOTMediumTextView 
   android:id="blabla"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

`com.yourapp.views` is the name of the package that contains your `DINOTMediumTextView` class.

Comment: thanks thats a good idea to create custom views but in my case I have to create custom TextView, EditText and Button.... the problem seems to be the extension in my case though

Comment: so create three custom views , one for each type of view, and then you can use them in your xml layout and you will not need to specify the typeFace each time :)